# Is it possible to edit the error template in Maya using python?

Tags: python, maya

I'm currently learning how to code in python and I was trying to raise exceptions in my code to make my tool more user-friendly. However, I find the template given by Maya to be too simple and I'd like to have more control over it.

Normally, the base template looks a little like this:

```
raise Exception(errorTitle)

>>> Result
# Error: errorTitle
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 1, in <module>
# Exception: errorTitle #
```

It works fine, but it doesn't let you give a more detailed description of the error. What I'm trying to achieve would look a little more like this:

```
raise Exception(errorTitle, errorDescription)

>>> Result
# Error: errorTitle
# errorDescription
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 1, in <module>
# Exception: errorTitle #
```

I also tried putting the `errorDescription` into `errorTitle` by adding a new line to the string, but since `errorTitle` is repeated twice, it becomes confusing quickly when trying to sort errors.

I know you can't really use multiple arguments in the raise function, so I was wondering if there was an error template in Maya I could reference instead of raising an error.

Alternatively, is there a way to create my own error template? If I can reuse the Traceback function and change the script bar color, it might be easier to just do that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken then exceptions are not designed this way. You could either use builtin exceptions and call them with `raise` or create your own exception class and raise them what is maybe the most appropriate in your case.

Comment: @haggikrey I tried calling it with `raise`, but it only takes the type of error and a short message. I suppose I could replace the error type so that I would get the error title and description all in one like this:
```raise Illegal character("The character used in this name is invalid, try using a letter (A-Z) or an underscore instead.")```


I don't know if it's better like this since normally you'd have "ValueError" or something there. I haven't looked at exception classes though so I'll definitely check that out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your desired result just like that:

```py
>>> raise Exception("Error Title\nError description that explains the problem")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception: Error Title
Error description that explains the problem
```

Or you may want to declare your custom exception class:

```py
class YourException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, title, description):
        super(YourException, self).__init__(title + "\n" + description)
```

and then you can use your original syntax:

```py
>>> raise YourException("Error Title", "Error description that explains the problem")
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
__main__.YourException: Error Title
Error description that explains the problem
```